# Consolidating various SNMP transactions and assigning the OID and result of each to unique variables for further processing

Tags: python, pysnmp, mib, human-readable

I am trying to write code that will have many SNMP transactions, some transactions could be bundled into the same `getCmd()` function of `PySNMP`. With that being said, I do not intend to print the value of the result of my SNMP transaction right away, sometimes further processing is needed. I.E: unpacking. Bundling two SNMP transactions looks like so:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData('somePasswd'),
           UdpTransportTarget(('somedev.example.com', 161)),
           ContextData(),
           #One MIB
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysName', '0')),
           #Second MIB
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('CISCO-CDP-MIB', 'cdpCacheAddress', 1,1)),
           lookupNames=True,
           lookupValues=True,
))

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                        errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

The way that I see it if I want to assign the value of a specific MIB to a variable, I'd have to put an if..elseif statement under my last for loop to compare the value of the MIB that I am looking for to the current value of the oid iterables(i think is the term). So, my code would change like so:

```
for oid, value in varBinds:
    if oid == 'SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0':
        #take specific actions
    elif oid == 'CISCO-CDP-MIB::cdpCacheAddress.1.1'
        #take different actions
```

I think this may be one way of doing things, however, I have a couple of questions:

1. Is this an efficient way of handling multiple SNMP transactions?
2. Is it better for code legibility to keep each SNMP Get transaction separate?
3. When I do the following my OIDs are converted to human-friendly,
           MIBS:

   ```
       for varBind in varBinds
               print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
   ```

But the following just gives me ugly oids:

```
     for oid, value in varBinds:
             print("oid:",oid,"Value",value):
```

by passing oid and value to my for loop, how do I end up with a
human-friendly mib instead of the ugly oid?

UPDATE:

Passing `.loadMibs` to `ObjectIdentity`, like so: `ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysName', '0').loadMibs('SNMPv2-MIB'))` still gave me an OID when printing `oid` and `value` like this: `for oid, value in varBinds:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pulling two managed objects (this is the SNMP parlance) at once is the right way to do it. It is the most efficient way to get data over the high-level SNMP API.

Once you get two managed objects in response, you can iterate over them and take actions accordingly - this is what your code seems to do. I personally do not see any issues there.

To resolve received variable-bindings (representing SNMP managed objects) against a MIB you just call `.prettyPrint()` on them:

```
for oid, value in varBinds:
    print("Name: ", oid.prettyPrint(), "Value: ", value.prettyPrint()):
```

If you want to branch your processing based on the OID value, the most efficient way is to compare those ugly OIDs:

```
for oid, value in varBinds:
    if oid == (1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 0):  # 'SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0':
        #take specific actions
```